# How can I instruct python 'filter' to ignore punctuation?

Tags: python, list, string-comparison

I'm attempting to write a small patch for a piece of python that checks a supplied string against a list of objects and returns the matching one if the object title field matches the supplied string.

The code does this using the filter function and passes a simple test to use to find the matches.

I want to alter the filter test to now ignore punctuation marks.

I started with this original code:

```
    res = (self._db_list(session).movies.filter(func.lower(MovieListMovie.title) == name.lower())
           .filter(MovieListMovie.year == year).first())
    if res:
        log.debug('found movie %s', res)
    return res
```

Essentially, it is using supplied 'name' and 'year' strings and seeing if any of the 'movie' objects in the 'movies' list have a title and year attribute that matches.  If so, it returns it.

And have tried modifying it to be:

```
    nameWithoutPunctuation = name.translate(None,string.punctuation)
    res = (self._db_list(session).movies.filter(func.lower(MovieListMovie.title).translate(None, string.punctuation) == nameWithoutPunctuation.lower())
           .filter(MovieListMovie.year == year).first())
    if res:
        log.debug('found movie %s', res)
    return res
```

But I'm getting an error that translate only accepts one variable, suggesting that I'm using it incorrectly.

Is this the right way to tell 'filter' that I want to ignore punctuation?  I'd rather not try and pull apart the 'movie' object or start fiddling with the lower level functions as they serve other functions too.

Comment: How about `string.replace('!', '')` ?

Comment: That seems workable @Vinny, but I can't figure out how to pass that to the filter correctly.  I've tried func.lower(MovieListMovie.title).replace(':','') and func.lower(MovieListMovie.title.replace(':','')) and it complains that "Neither 'Function' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'replace'"

Comment: What is returned from the function call `func.lower(MovieListMovie.title)` ?

Comment: I tried `print func.lower(MovieListMovie.title)` to see.  It printed `lower(movie_list_movies.title)` to the screen. (@Vinny).  I also tried prepending `func.` to the call to replace: `func.lower(MovieListMovie.title).func.replace(':','')` but that still fails with the same error as above.

It feels like I'm just completely missing how `filter` works...